# React Native: Binding Template stored in Database

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am storing FAQ for my app into the database table which is formatted in react native template.

e.g.

```
&lt;Text&gt;You can&lt;Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}&gt; earn up to 1,000 Sparrow points &lt;/Text&gt;during the test period&lt;/Text&gt;
```

further, decoding is done using html-entities node package which gives me string as below.

```
"<Text>
    You can<Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}> earn up to 1,000 Sparrow points </Text>during the test period
  </Text>"

render(){
   var data = [];
   data.push(this.state.faq);
   return(
   <View>
      {data}
   </View>
)
}
```

Issue: It is binding as string, template is not getting parsed.